# Return a function from multiple derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a base class and multiple derived classes from it. Each derived class has a constructor that accepts parameters that were initialized in the base class. All of the constructors are different, however they all accept one common parameter, let's call it `Name`.

Is there a way for me to display every derived class' name in a shorter way than calling them one after another?

Here's an example. Let's say my base class is `Father` and my derived classes are `Brother, Sister, HalfBrother, HalfSister` and this is my driver file:

```
cout << Brother::Brother().getName() << endl
     << Sister::Sister().getNAme() << endl
     << HalfBrother::HalfBrother().getNAme() << endl
     << HalfSister::HalfSister().getName() << endl;
```

This will return them fine, but is there a simpler way to do this so that I can get all the names from all the derived classes without having to write them one by one?

Comment: I dont think that we can do like this but may be if we use super() or something like it then it may be possible. I am waiting for reply(answer) to your question.

Comment: Why did you construct temporary objects to print their names and where is this common parameter name - I see they did not take any parameters?

Comment: why not make `getName()` a method in Father? by doing so, you are just iterating thru your list of Father reference/pointer and call `father->getName()`

Comment: Are these names specific to the classes, or specific to the individual objects you create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a static registry of classes, and populate it from constructors of static members that you insert into classes that you would like to register.

In the header:

```
class Registration {
    static vector<string> registered;
public:
    static void showRegistered() {
        for (int i = 0 ; i != registered.size() ; i++) {
            cout << registered[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    Registration(string name) {
        registered.push_back(name);
    }
};
```

In the CPP file:

```
vector<string> Registration::registered;
```

With this class in hand, you can do this:

In the headers:

```
class A {
    static Registration _registration;
};

class B {
    static Registration _registration;    
};

class C {
    static Registration _registration;    
};
```

In the CPP files:

```
Registration A::_registration("quick");
Registration B::_registration("brown");
Registration C::_registration("fox");
```

This last part is key: declarations of the static `_registration` variables have a side effect - they insert the name into the `vector<string> registered` of the `Registration` class, in no specific order. You can now retrieve the names, print them out, or do whatever you want with them. I added a member-function for printing, but obviously you are not limited by it.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/U3LK0e) - it prints

```
quick
brown
fox
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I am not sure if I understand your question.  As said in comment, you should make getName() a method in Father.

```
class Father {
public:

    Father(string name) : m_name(name) {
    }

    string& getName() {
        return m_name;
    }

private:
    string m_name;
};

class Brother : public Father {
public:
    Brother(string name) : Father(name) {
    }
};

class Sister : public Father {
public:
    Sister(string name) : Father(name) {
    }
};
```

So you can have something like:

```
vector<Father *> fathers;
Brother brother("...");
Sister sister("....");

father.push_back(&brother);
father.push_back(&sister);

for (vector<Father*>::iterator itr = fathers.begin();
        itr != fathers.end();
        ++itr) {
    cout << (*itr)->getName() <<endl;
}
```